# Maven ususally place the pom.xml in the jar during build, but two different pom.xml?

Tags: java, maven

[image]

### Both folders have a pom.xml !

The pom in the byte-buddy folder references the byte-buddy-dep's pom.

How to identify the main pom.xml?

This is the jar: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/bytebuddy/byte-buddy/1.10.17/byte-buddy-1.10.17.jar

The aim is to build a tool that analyses a large number of JARs and tries to find the POMs inside of them.

Comment: Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) pages.

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri What cant be reproduced?

Comment: Please add your POM to the question.

Comment: @JFabianMeier Both from bytebuddy?  I have no pom.xml because I have no maven project.

Comment: The correct POM should be in the `byte-buddy` folder. You can compare it with the POM next to the JAR in the repository.

Comment: @JFabianMeier Since I need to do this programatically, have you a source from an official reference?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do programmatically? Find POMs for JARs in Maven Central?

Comment: @JFabianMeier No, I have a offline server who have no access to maven central. Someone gave me a thumbdrive having thousands of jars generated by maven to install them to the server.

Comment: Please ask a new question with that information.

Comment: @JFabianMeier No, this question is answerable.

Comment: With a new question, I would a have written you an answer. This question is closed, and therefore I can't. So, good luck with your problem.

Comment: @JFabianMeier You can answer now.

Answer (score 0):

Maven puts the POMs into the directory `META-INF/maven/{groupId}/{artifactId}`.

There may be other POMs as well in `META-INF/maven`. These usually come from other JARs that are shaded into the original JAR.

So first determine the groupId and artifactId of the JAR, then look for the POM inside the JAR.

Comment: `determine the groupId and artifactId` ok, how to do that?